# How to write Japanese in GIMP text layer?

Tags: gimp, text, japanese

I am using mac 10.10. My keyboard input source is set to Hiragana, but when I type into a Gimp text layer, the regular latin characters appear and not the Japanese that I expected. How do I get this to work?

Comment: You probably need to use a font that supports japanese letters (japanese fonts) do you have any japanese fonts?

Comment: @Aziz dont know really. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: http://www.freejapanesefont.com/ download to your heart's content and make sure to check the licesne of each font

Comment: @Aziz your suggestion did not work. I just installed the font you recommended and tried to type in hiragana and latin characters appeared.

Comment: have a look here http://www.justskins.com/forums/illustrator-cs-can-t-170722.html "Under the keyboard menu select Open International ...
Click Options...
Disable Try to match keyboard with text"

Comment: @Aziz I am using GIMP not Illustrator

Comment: my mistake, all sources point to using a correct font - http://gimpforums.com/thread-japanese-text-input - try this one http://www.dafont.com/japanese.font BTW what happens if you copy-paste japanese characters?

Comment: What happens when you type the Japanese text in another app and then copy-paste it? Nothing happens? Squares/missing-glyph icons? @Aziz OS X includes quite a lot of fonts that support Japanese. Latin text appearing instead of the Japanese text entered in the Japanese IME does not sound like a font issue, but a software issue. The conversion that the IME is supposed to perform does not happen, for some reason. If it were a font issue, the expected outcome would be squares or Unicode missing-glyphs icons, not just Latin text.

Comment: What Gimp version, 2.8 or 2.10. Have you got the problem when you type directly and when you paste or just when you type?

Answer (score 0):

I just entered it in Google (just a text field I can copy-paste out of quickly) and copy-pasted. It worked with the sans-serif font, and I was satisfied.

This was on Linux, though, so maybe something prevented conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I switched my Mac keyboard to Japanese and "Kana Table" input method. In Gimp I chose the text tool and set the font to M+ 1m Bold and made a type layer in Japanese.[image: Screenshot of Gimp Japanese type layer]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write in japanese you need to use japanese fonts and not latin or others. 
You can find online a lot of fonts http://www.freejapanesefont.com/
Switch the language of your mac in japanese ( system > language > Add Japanese ). Then select japanese and try to type in gimp.
After if you want to write english again come back to system preference.